# Slow Performance In WebSphere Prepared Statement

Tags: java, performance, websphere

We are using a WebSphere / DB2 system for our application. We frequently see the following in a stack trace as the slowest component (the setObject method on com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.[image: WSJdbcPreparedStatement]. Any thought why this would be....why a socketRead during the setting of a prepared statement parameter.

Thanks,

Comment: WebSphere just delegates setObject to the driver impl, so this looks like a problem with the DB2 driver.  Can you confirm that a socketRead still occurs when you take WebSphere out of the equation?

Comment: Q: How complex is the query?

Comment: Does not appear to be related to the query. We observe similar slowness in other low level JDK functions like class loading.